# Policy Gradient in Partial Observability

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, policy-gradients

Let $\pi_{\theta}$ be a policy. Then, I was able to follow through the proof of: $\nabla_\theta J=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim\pi_{\theta}}[\Sigma_{i=1}^T \nabla_\theta log(p_{\theta}(a_i|s_i)R(\tau)]$, where $J=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim\pi_{\theta}}[R(\tau)]$.

My professor said something along the lines that this equation is also true in the case of partial observability. Can someone please explain how is this the case?

In particular, I need to prove $\nabla_\theta J=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim\pi_{\theta}}[\Sigma_{i=1}^T \nabla_\theta log(p_{\theta}(a_i|o_i)R(\tau)]$, where $R(\tau)=\Sigma_{t=1}^T r(s_t,a_t)$.